# Visual Studio ASP.NET CS1504 Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

i just wanted to start my asp.net project, but it fails and return this errors.
How can i fix that? I didn't know why these errors appear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File "*Global.asax.cs*" has already been deleted from the filesystem. І suppose that the file shows up in the Visual Studio solution with a yellow warning icon next to it. You need to check in Windows Explorer that the file exists in those locations